# Java regex pattern matching start with

Tags: java, string

I have a file containing lots of lines.
I want to find a specific line starting with "msql".

I have tried many regex combinations but not get any idea.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^msql");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
```

or

```
s.matches("^(msql).*$")  or s.matches("^msql")
```

please suggest correct regex for finding a line start with "msql".

EDIT:-

i have file data like this:-

```
eventlogger 0 0 1 1 1 10
expireserv 0 0 1 1 1 10 "
partEOLserv 0 0 1 1 1 10
msqlpdmm81dd 0 0 25 25 25
```

and my code.

```
String s = br.readLine();
while (s != null) {
    //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^msql");
    //("^(msql).*$")
    //Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.startsWith("msql")) {
        System.out.println(s);

    }

    s = br.readLine();
}
```

still am not able to find line.

Comment: Why not just use `String.startsWith()`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis:- i have tried this but not success. please view edited question.

Comment: maybe it contain extra spaces at the start, `s.matches("^\\s*msql.*$")`

Comment: If you change the print out in the loop to: `System.out.println("[" + s + "]");` what gets printed out?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Thanks. It's working now. forget to consider spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading only first line and hence no match found.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File f = new File("example.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
        String temp = null;
        while ((temp=br.readLine())!=null) {
            if (temp.startsWith("msql")){
                System.out.println("Match found: "+temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

and output is `Match found: msqlpdmm81dd 0 0 25 25 25`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex for matching the content is correct. I do not know why are you facing problem. I have tried your program and it is working.
I m adding the code with regex below.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<filepath\\filename.extension>"));
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.matches("^(msql).*$")){
                System.out.println(s);
            } else {
                System.out.println("didnt matched");
            }
        }
```

You can also check the condition using

```
if (s.startsWith("msql"))
```

This is also working fine.
I have created an text file in my local and saved your data in it. And I m getting the following output.

```
didnt matched
didnt matched
didnt matched
msqlpdmm81dd 0 0 25 25 25
```

I think this should work.